# In which chapter did Tincanpy grow hair?

Tags: d-gray-man

In which chapter of the manga did Tincanpy grow hair and Allen's hair grow longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened in volume 16, chapter 159. There was a bottle of hair tonic which caused different effects. Below is a scan of the page where it takes place.

[image: Hair Tonic]

Comment: @user31031 no problem. Please mark it as accepted if it solved your question using the check mark on the left.